# How to unit test public methods that use same private methods?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, nunit

I need some guidance with my software testing.

I'm over-complicating things, but I'm too fixated to see what I'm doing wrong, or an alternate way of doing things.

I have several public methods that are using the same private method.

The private method itself:

- has to handle many scenarios for its specific role
- works closely with fields/properties/methods in the same instance

Say that the private method needs 5 tests to cover all scenarios, and is used by 6 public methods.

**Question**

- *Do I then need at least `5x6` tests?*
- *How can I re-use the private method's tests for each public method?*
- *Are there any examples/articles out there on refactoring repeated tests?*

**Example**

*OnStartup()*

```
- if_file_exists_load_entries           ()
- if_file_missing_load_last             ()
- if_no_files_create_new_entries        ()
- if_exception_clear_entries_and_log    ()
- loaded_entries_init_called            ()
- Other tests
```

*OnUserLoadCustom()*

```
- if_file_exists_load_entries           _AND_STORE_AS_LAST()
- if_file_missing_load_last             _AND_STORE_AS_LAST_AND_WARNING_MESSAGE()
- if_no_files_create_new_entries        _AND_WARNING_MESSAGE()
- if_exception_clear_entries_and_log    _AND_ERROR_MESSAGE()
- loaded_entries_init_called            _AND_SUCCESS_MESSAGE()
- Other tests
```

*OnRecover()*

```
- if_file_exists_load_entries           _AND_INFO_MESSAGE()
- if_file_missing_load_last             _AND_INFO_MESSAGE()
- if_no_files_create_new_entries        _AND_INFO_MESSAGE()
- if_exception_clear_entries_and_log    _AND_ERROR_MESSAGE_AND_SHUTDOWN()
- loaded_entries_init_called            _AND_SUCCESS_MESSAGE()
- Other tests
```

I'm considering encapsulating the private method using the Strategy pattern, so I can test it (and the public methods) in isolation.

However, I don't feel right using one because:

- I do not intend to have interchangeable behaviours at runtime
- Using the pattern for the sake of easier testing seems wrong

**Update #1**

My question pertains to testing the public interface for the private method's behaviour. But I end up with lots of duplicate test methods (see my examples above).

With a strategy pattern, I reckon all I need are:

- Test all the paths in the strategy (essentially, testing the private
  method)
- Verify that all public methods invokes the strategy (Can easily use a mock object here, and verify that it's been called)

But like I mentioned, I don't think I should introduce a pattern just for the sake of easier testing. I'm holding off on this approach unless I really have to.

---

**Update #2**

First attempt at reducing duplication:

- Private method tests grouped into its own class (Behaviour1Test)

  - GetTestCases() returns list of test cases related to this behaviour
- All public methods that needs this test implements interface that exposes

  - Arrange()
  - Act()
  - Assert()

For example:

```
// Public method tests
[TestFixture]
public class PublicMethodTests: IBehaviour1Test
{
    // Behaviour 1
    Behaviour1Test _behaviour1;
    IEnumerable<TestCaseData> Behaviour1TestCases{ get { return _behaviour1.GetTestCases(); } }
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("Behaviour1TestCases")]
    public void RunBehaviour1Test(Action<IBehaviour1Test> runTestCase)
    {
        runTestCase(this);
    }

    // ==============================
    // Behaviour 1 Arrange/act/assert
    void IBehaviour1Test.Arrange(){}
    void IBehaviour1Test.Assert(object result){}
    object IBehaviour1Test.Act()
    {
        return _model.PublicMethod();        
    }

    // Other tests
}

// Implement this in order to run Behaviour1 test cases
interface IBehaviour1Test
{
    void Arrange(); 
    object Act();
    void Assert(object retValue);
}

// Collection of tests for behaviour 1
public class Behaviour1Test
{
    // Generate test cases
    IEnumerable<TestCaseData>() GetTestCases()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData((Action<IBehaviour1Test>)Test_1);
        yield return new TestCaseData((Action<IBehaviour1Test>)Test_2);
        yield return new TestCaseData((Action<IBehaviour1Test>)Test_3);
    }

    void Test_1(IBehaviour1Test impl)
    {
        // Arrange
        impl.Arrange(); // public method's arrange
        Test1Setup(); // Arrange for this test

        // Act
        var result = impl.Act();

        // Assert
        Test1Assert(result); // Assert for this test
        impl.Assert(result); // Assert on public method

    }

    void Test_2(IBehaviour1Test impl){}
    void Test_3(IBehaviour1Test impl){}
}
```

This way, if I need to add a new test case for the private method's behaviour, I just need to add it once in the BehaviourTest, and all public method tests that contains it will be updated.

[image]

Comment: You dont test private methods, only public methods. passing in as much data as you wish for all the scenarios you wish to test

Comment: If you really need to make sure that those methods are getting called, you might want to extract those methods into another class in which your current class requires. EDIT: Like you mentioned, strategy pattern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the same philosophy in your tests as you do in your application code. If common functionality can be extracted into helper methods or classes then you should do so. It will save you the code duplication and will help you refactor later if the private method changes.

I imagine you have a lot of common setup, teardown, assert and verify code that could be generalized.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're absolutely right! My real problem has nothing to do with unit testing, but how to remove duplicate code. That's given me some food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you don't test private methods.  You test the methods that use the private methods thoroughly, and it all checks out, the private method "works".

If you really wanted peace of mind, you could use reflection to execute the private method, that way you can test it in isolation.

With respect to test refactoring, you should of course have setup and teardown routines to handle those respective functions.  I wouldn't get into the Strategy pattern in a test, just create non-test methods in your test class that has chunks of functionality that you need for multiple tests and use them appropriately.  For example, if you private method can affect 5 fields, and you need to test those 5 fields more than once, I would create a method like

```
private void verifyField(expected1, extpected2, ....){
     equals(actual1, expected1, 'expected1 correct);
     ....
}
```

and use it where appropriate.

Comment: my problem is precisely because I do not want to test the private method, but the public methods that use it. My public methods share some common behavior (captured by the private method). As you said, I should be testing the public interfaces instead. But this leads to many duplicate code in my tests (see my example above). I'm repeating the same test for the common behaviour in every public interface. I would like to know if there's a better way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the private method into a helper class. Then test its functionality separately and mock it in the other tests. The functionality within the private method has nothing to do with what you are trying to test in the other methods -- it only provides input. Most private methods are usually just helper methods waiting to be freed.